# How to show a set of vectors does not span a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant

Let's say I am given a $4\times4$ matrix and I am to determine whether the columns of that matrix span $\mathbb R^4$. Please tell me if I'm correct:

One way to determine that is to calculate the matrix's determinant, if it is non-zero, then there is a unique solution and not only does it span R4, but it also is a basis for it, since it means that the column vectors are independent.

I'm assuming this is correct for now. But what if the determinant is equal to zero? From what I know, this does not imply the system is inconsistent, it might also be that there is an infinite number of solutions . If there is an infinite number of solutions, then the column vectors still span the vector space.(please tell me if that last sentence is valid as well)

If this is true, that would mean that my book, which only uses this method to determine whether a set of vector spans a vector space, assumes that that set actually spans the vector space and they don't think about the potential situation, in which the determinant is 0. And indeed, in every example they have given, they use that method and the result is that the determinant is 0, and so they conclude that the the set spans a vector space.

However, it would seem strange to me that they're using an inconclusive method, that is why I have doubts about my initial assumption that, if a determinant is not equal to 0, then the solutions are either infinite or they don't exist.

Could you please clarify this to me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: in $\mathbb R ^n$,  a set of n vectors spans the space if and only if the determinant of the matrix they form is nonzero.

Comment: Is it correct to say that if the determinant is equal to 0, then there are either no solutions or an infinite number of solutions?

Comment: If the determinant is zero, it means that column vectors span a proper subspace $V$ of $R^4$ (not the whole space!). The existence of solutions in this case is equivalent to say that the right hand side if our system also belongs to $V$. Conversely, if for at least one right hand side there is an infinity of solutions, then the determinant is zero and the column vectors do not span the whole space.

Comment: But if there is an infinite number of solutions, doesn't that imply that the vectors do indeed span the vector space but they are dependent?

Comment: No. You have 4 vectors describing a 3-dimensional subspace. So you could loosely say that you have one vector "too many". That is what dependence means. You can get rid of one of your vectors, and still describe the 3-dim subspace fully.

Comment: When the determinant is zero, there are infinitely many solutions for some $b$'s and there are no solutions for other infinitely many other $b$'s. Your problem isn't the infinite solutions, it's the ones for which there are no solutions.

Comment: So what is the concept of base for? I thought that a base is a set of vectors that spans the vector space AND is independent, which differentiates the concept of a span, which only requires that the vectors span the vector space but they may or may not be independent.

Comment: A basis is the bare minimum amount of information to needed to generate your space. A spanning set which is not a basis gives you extra superfluous information. It is natural to have a terminology differentiating the two.

Comment: I understand that. But, according to M.Wind's comment above, the determinant cannot be zero because there are then dependent vectors in the spanning set, so I have to make sure that the set spans the vector space and all its vectors are independent. But that's the definition of a base... So what in this case differentiates a base from a spanning set?( I thought that for a set to span a vector space, it did not necessarily have to include only independent vectors)

Comment: It is true that a spanning set does not have to be independent. For instance, take any basis and add as many vectors as you like; you still get a spanning set, but a dependent one.

I think that the reason why you are confused lies in the following basic result in linear algebra: In $\mathbb R^n$, an independent set of exactly $n$ vectors is automatically a basis (no need to check whether it is spanning), and likewise, a spanning set of exactly $n$ vectors is necessarily independent.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you!